# Submit a form without reloading of document

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html

Having a sign-in form coded in HTML5, once **submit** button is pressed, what is an optimal way to ask server to check credentials **without reloading** a document? May I use **script** to ask server to validate credentials and return *(for example)* a `sessionID` and if null is returned (if such credentials are invalid), show an error message and let user to correct his credentials? ...or some similar scenario.

A simple HTML5/Script code showing such behavior will be appreciate.

Comment: Erm... AJAX, perhaps?

Comment: For not reloading the document you put this in your javascript:
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); });

Comment: @niels123: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, technically speaking it is JavaScript, it just happens to be in the form of a library

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is a pretty good plugin written by the creator of jQuery and other contributors.

You will have to use javascript in order to make a call to the server without reloading the whole page.

As the documentation points out the following code is enough to make a form submit via AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 

    // other available options: 
    //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
    //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
    //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
    //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

    // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
    //timeout:   3000 
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

Where myForm1 is the ID of your HTML Form.

**EDIT**

As the comment point out, if you are not using jQuery the following javascript code would also work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendToServer()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
          // This is when you receive a response from the server
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","your_page.php?name=your_name&surname=your_surname",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return sendToServer();">
</form>
```

Comment: No one mentioned jQuery, the question isn't tagged jQuery. You can't simply assume he's using jQuery and throw a plugin at him.